# How to get firstname in autocomplete when adding new members in og group?

Tags: 7, organic-groups, ajax

I have created the group in og.

When adding the user for the group, In autocomplete its been displaying the user's email ID.

```
function custom_form_alter($form,&$form_state){ if($form['#id']== 'og-ui-add-users'){
     $form['og_user']['name']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'user/autocomplete';
}
```

}

But I want to get the name instead of email ID.

I have tried to change the user/autocomplete in hook_form_alter,but its displaying email id only

Is there any way to get name instead of email ID ?

Tell me how to sort out this problem?

Comment: have you written query.

Comment: No, I didnt write query

Comment: Can you please update your question with coding.this might be useful.

Comment: added the code,just altered the form, But I dont know this method is right

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get a clear idea, anyway please [Check This](http://www.webomelette.com/how-to-create-autocomplete-widget-drupal-7).